# Recursive split while delimiter exists in the string and then create an object

Tags: javascript, recursion

Suppose I have the following string: `plan.details.notes` *(Note: this string can have more/less sub nodes)* and I have a value that should be set to it once it has been *destructured*, ie. "hello".

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
{
  plan {
    details {
      notes: "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

I currently have the following code:

```
function recursiveSplitIntoObject(string, delimiter, value) {
  if (!string) return {}

  let stringToSplit = string
  const returnObj = {}

  while (stringToSplit.indexOf(delimiter) >= 0) {
    const split = string.split(delimiter)
    returnObj[split[0]] = { [split[1]]: value }
    stringToSplit = split[1]
  }

  console.log(returnObj)
}
```

I'm not sure how to assign a dynamic object inside the `[split[1]]: value`. I maybe close but I can't figure it out. Can anyone lead me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last key, process all other keys and finally assign the last key:

```js
function recursiveSplitIntoObject(string, delimiter, value) {
    let start = {},
        curr = start,
        keys = string.split(delimiter),
        last = keys.pop()

    for (let key of keys)
        curr = (curr[key] = {})
    
    curr[last] = value

    return start
}

console.log(
    recursiveSplitIntoObject('plan.details.notes', '.', 'hello'))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, I just didn't know how to execute. It worked as expected! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In that case I would really consider using recursion, as it simplifies the way we can think of this problem.

The idea is to split the string into chunks using the delimeter, and when reaching to the last piece, assign the value, otherwise, call the recursive function with the tail of the array:

```js
function rec(chunks, value) {
 if (chunks.length === 1) {
    return { [chunks[0]]: value };
 }
 return { [chunks[0]]: rec(chunks.slice(1), value) };
}

function recrusiveSetValue(str, value) {
  const chunks = str.split('.');
  return rec(chunks, value);
}

console.log(recrusiveSetValue('foo.bar.baz', 'hello'))
```

Comment: I tested this and it is working as expected. I went with @gog's answer because it was what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`reduceRight` makes this a one-liner:

```js
const recursiveSplitIntoObject = (string, delimiter, value) =>
  string .split (delimiter) .reduceRight ((v, n) => ({[n]: v}), value)


console .log (recursiveSplitIntoObject ('plan.details.notes', '.', 'hello'))
```

We simply build this from the inside out, starting with `'hello'`, then `{notes: 'hello'}`, then `{details: {notes: 'hello'}}` and finally `{plan: {details: {notes: 'hello'}}}`.

You could also look at [more generic tools](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20hydrate), used in the case where you want to create a single object from multiple pairs such as `['plan.details.notes', 'hello']`.  I keep handy a function like `setPath` that would let you add your path into an existing object:

```js
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const recursiveSplitIntoObject = (string, delimiter, value, original) =>
  setPath (string .split (delimiter)) (value) (original)


console .log (
  recursiveSplitIntoObject (
    'plan.details.notes', 
    '.', 
    'hello', 
    {foo: 'bar', plan: {summary: 'world'}}
  )
) 
// {
//   foo: "bar",
//   plan: {
//     summary: "world",
//     detail": {
//       notes: "hello"
//     }
//   }
// }
```

This may be overkill here, but it could be good to keep in mind.